# Need to pull all users with SIDhistory but have never logged in

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to get a script together to pull a list of all users with a SIDhistory but have never used their account and dump that into a CSV.  This is what I have so far.

Get-aduser -filter {sidhistory -like "*"} -properties lastlogondate | export-csv c:\users\desktop\sidhistoryneverloggedin.csv

I have it to the point that I can get a list of all user swith a SID history, but I can't figure out how to just pull the ones with no logon activity.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe it through Where-Object like this:

```
 Get-aduser -filter {sidhistory -like "*"} -properties lastlogondate | Where-Object {$_.lastlogondate -eq $null} | Export-Csv output.csv
```

The lastlogindate attribute will be $null if the account has never logged in.